# Assertion error in date conversion in python dataframe

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-3.8

I am using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(sf['date'][1:4], format('%m-%d-%Y'))
```

The `dataframe` is as follows:

```
sf['date'][1:4]
1    6-1-2021
2    6-11-2021
3    6-12-2021
4    8-1-2021
Name: date, dtype: object
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 2069, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    assert errors in ["raise", "ignore", "coerce"]
AssertionError
```

I am not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a wrong syntax for the `format=` parameter. Try to amend the syntax as follows:

```
pd.to_datetime(sf['date'][1:4], format='%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: I am getting cross eyed .. I need to go for a walk :)

Comment: @Zanam  Haha, take a rest !  :-)